# difference between readfile() and fopen()

Tags: php, file-read

These two codes both do the same thing in reading files , so what's the main difference ?

1-First code :

```
$handle = fopen($file, 'r');
$data = fread($handle, filesize($file));
```

2-Second code :

```
readfile($file);
```

Comment: So like ... where is the `fileopen()` bit of your code to go with the TITLE?

Comment: Does PHP even have a `fileopen()`? Not AFAIK.

Comment: @RiggsFolly sry it was mistake , i changed the title

Comment: `Fileread()` send the file to the output buffer directly `fread()` reads the file into a string variable. All this and a lot more is available for reference in the PHP Manual

Comment: @tnx for your answer and warning about title , are they different in reading speed ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a significant difference between `fread()` and `readfile()`.

First, `readfile()` does a number of things that `fread()` does not. `readfile()` opens the file for reading, reads it, and then prints it to the output buffer all in one go. `fread()` only does one of those things: *it reads bytes from a given file handle*.

Additionally, `readfile()` has some benefits that `fread()` does not. For example, it can take advantage of [memory-mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) where available rather than slower disk reads. This significantly increases the performance of reading the file since it delegates the process away from PHP itself and more towards operating system calls.

### Errata

> *I previously noted that `readfile()` could run without PHP (this is corrected below).*

For truly large files (think several gigs like media files or large archive backups), you may want to consider delegating the reading of the file away from PHP entirely with `X-Sendfile` headers to your webserver instead (so that you don't keep your PHP worker tied up for the length of an upload that could potentially take hours).

So you could do something like this instead of `readfile()`:

```php
<?php
/* process some things in php here */
header("X-Sendfile: /path/to/file");
exit; // don't need to keep PHP busy for this
```

Comment: tnx for the comprehensive explanation , just one more thing are they different in speed ?

Comment: Sure, it could. Reading an **mmaped** file can be significantly faster that reading from disk (especially a mechanical disk, for example).

Answer (score 2):

Reading the docs, [readfile](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.readfile) reads the whole content and writes it into STDOUT.

`$data = fread($handle, filesize($file));`

While fread puts the content into the variable $data.